# How to add rest above a note in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, rests, slurs

I'm trying to typeset the following snippet of violin music. My first idea was to use two voices here but then I would not be able to make a slur between them. Is it possible without using manual placement of notes?

[image: An upper voice of sixteenth rests and sixteenth notes, and a lower voice of eight notes. The notes in the lower voice are slurred to the notes in the upper voice.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the lower voice is eighth notes and the upper voice is sixteenth notes, my recommendation would be to use separate voices. Here is one possible solution:

```
\version "2.19.63"

music = \relative c'' {
  <<
    {
      f16\rest b, e\rest a, 
    }
    \\
    {
      \autoBeamOff
      f8 e
    }
    \\
    {
      \autoBeamOff
      \override NoteColumn.force-hshift = 0
      \hideNotes f16_( b) e,_( a)
    }
  >>
}

\score {
  \new Staff \music
  \layout { }
}
```

which compiles

[image]

Another option would be to put `f16 b e, a` in a single voice, but change the flags on the lower two pitches to be eighth notes instead of sixteenth notes.

Comment: Minor quibble:  The "hooks" of short rests should go in spaces (not on lines), i.e. that second rest looks better centred on "F" or possibly "D"  (not "E").